# Sending web push notifications from Laravel

Tags: laravel, push-notification

I have a website running **Laravel** in the back-end, where users can create reports for other users.

When the report is created I would like to send a push notification to recipient user's desktop.

Do I need to use services like *Pusher*, *OneSignal*?

Any useful site with examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Your question

You could use Pusher, Redis/Socket.io, Pubnub, etc. Which one to use? well, this is more an opinion-based question.

These services broadcast events, then in your client apps (like your web front-end) you configure the client-side libraries of the service you choose to subscribe (to channels) and listen to those events.

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting) explains it better.

## Examples/tutorials

#### Pusher

[This](https://blog.pusher.com/create-web-notifications-using-laravel-pusher/) is a tutorial published by the Pusher team.

#### Redis/Socket.io

[This one](https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io)
is a Laracasts series about this.

Just google.

---

## Update

There is a Laravel-specific alternative, a package created exclusively for Laravel:

#### Laravel WebSockets

- [This is](https://freek.dev/1228-introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php) the post talking about the package and its inner working.
- [This is](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) the repo.
- [Here](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) you have the documentation.

Comment: Do these services works even when the browser is down?

Comment: Your server will fire events, those events are received by the service who will breadcast the events, the clients that wil be listening to those events wil be notified.

Comment: there is a difference between websockets "browser have to be opened" and web push "browser doesnt have to be opened"

Comment: Try this Laravel package [pushmix/laravel-web-notification](https://github.com/pushmix/laravel-web-notification). To push web notifications you will require to obtain user permission and store device token to push notifications to.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to show Native Desktop notification then i would suggest Web Push notification.  In this way once user subscribed to push notification ,they will get real time notification and does not need to be on your website.
https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webpush